# In Lyx, how to add a centered header over an equation in `aligned`

Tags: header-footer, amsmath

In Lyx, how to add centered headers? E.g. how to add headers like `Equation 1` and `Equation 2` above each equation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}x & =2(a+b) & y & =3(x+2)\\
 & =2a+2b &  & =3x+6
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

The header should be centered on the equation middle (not on the equal sign).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the best solution but it works:

[image]

```
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\textrm{Equation 1} & \longleftrightarrow & \textrm{Equation 2}\\
\begin{aligned}[t]x & =2(3+5)\\
 & =6+10\\
 & =15.99
\end{aligned}
 &  & \begin{aligned}[t]y & =s(x)\\
 & =5x+3p
\end{aligned}
\end{array}
\]
```

This is done by:

- Selecting both equations, embedding them into an array environment
  using `Inset|Math|Array Environment`.
- Then adding a row at the top of the array
  using button `Add Row` of the `Table` toolbar.
  [image]
- Adding text in the new row
  e.g. with `\textrm`.
- Aligning vertically both `aligned`
  using again the table toolbar.

I added a middle column to the array for illustration.